Portable battery power stations for critical loads without backfeeding the grid
Some context for my questions first, then the actual questions with a diagram at the end.
Portable battery power stations or solar generators -- such as those made by Jackery, Ecoflow, Bluetti, Anker, etc. -- are becoming popular in the USA, and they are capable of inverting large amounts of power from their batteries. Units like the Ecoflow Delta Pro are capable of outputting 7,000W of AC power, which rivals gas generators.
These units are also commonly used as an uninterruptible power supply (UPS), meaning that they are always plugged into a standard 120VAC outlet. While plugged in, the unit is both charging its batteries and (usually) passing through AC power from the wall outlet.
Let's describe a hypothetical grid down situation. For a unit with UPS capability, a relay closes and the connected AC loads are fed by the unit's inverter and batteries. Most people probably don't unplug their unit from the wall outlet because they want it to charge back up immediately when the grid comes back online. Kilowatts of power are being generated, and hopefully it's only being sent to the unit's outlets, because otherwise the unit is directly connected to the grid via an open (non-interlocked) branch circuit in the main panel.
In my mind it's important to draw a distinction from a standard whole-house generator in such a grid down situation. Whole-house generators are typically connected to the main panel with an interlock kit, which closes the main panel's breaker to prevent backfeeding the grid. Larger units might use an automatic transfer switch that is UL 1008 compliant/listed. Smaller units might still use a critical loads panel with its own interlock. Long story short, these options give you a high degree of certainty that your generator won't backfeed the grid through code-compliant mechanical means.
Now that the context is established, the actual questions!

What (if any) regulations/codes exist to ensure that a power station in such a UPS configuration can't backfeed the grid?
Are the (likely) cheap relays in these power stations sufficiently reliable to ensure no backfeeding from the breaker, or is there some other mechanical/electrical reason internal to the units that make that impossible?

And one last question that's really the basis for the previous questions:
If it is safe to use large-capacity power stations like a UPS, leaving their input always connected to the grid with no interlock at the panel, is there anything wrong with using one to constantly provide power to a critical loads panel via a generator inlet and interlock, while having the power station itself connected to a branch circuit from the main panel?
In other words, imagine a power station's AC input is permanently plugged into an appropriately rated branch circuit fed from the main panel. Then, an appropriately rated extension cord connects the power station's inverter output to the inlet on a transfer switch that feeds a critical loads panel. This ensures that the power station is always receiving grid power (when the grid is up), allowing it to recharge its batteries or provide passthrough power. Simultaneously, the power station is always feeding the critical load panel's circuits, ensuring that they won't lose power when the grid goes down.
Here's a diagram to explain further:


@DIY75, thanks for the reply. I should clarify that "connected to" refers to the input power of the power station, not the output (inverter output) that the power station generates. Basically, when you plug it in to charge it.

There are some power stations that advertise UPS-like functionality with pass-through power and switching in X milliseconds.  Read the docs to determine if X is low enough for your needs.   In your last example it sounds like you are feeding entire critical-loads circuits that way, permanently fed by the power station output and never connected to the grid.  So I don't even see where there is a question?  Your power station must not backfeed to the main panel via its input .... you should verify that!  But I'd be surprised, unless you buy it on Temu for $1.95.

I'm interested in the economics of running 10 domestic circuits from a battery power station.   You can't run your fridge, pumps, assorted lights, and internet for 12 hours on any reasonable priced station. I think?  What is your plan?  I think you need to run your internet and a couple of bathroom lights for an hour or so til you can fire up the gas generator.

@jay613, thanks for the reply. A couple thoughts: 1) I'm aware of the claims of the UPS-like functionality from manufacturers, but the basis for my wordy context and question is that I don't understand how they can ensure they don't backfeed through the AC charge port. Like, the engineering or electronics involved, and why people just trust the manufacturers that they won't backfeed. Is there a fault scenario where it's technically possible they could? 2) Yeah I'm talking about 10Kw+ battery systems, which have come down in price a lot. With solar and a gas generator as a backup to charge it.

Sounds great.  You cannot ask questions here about how specific commercial products work or whether they work as advertised.  Read the docs, ask the manufacturer, and test it to see if it back feeds.     I'd be very surprised.  Only people using it like you would even ask the question.  All the people who have one for work or camping or whatever ... they'll just leave them plugged in without thinking about what happens during blackouts.

These cheap portable power stations are in a different class than grid-forming battery inverters such as the Tesla PowerWall.   And these are different from generators and UPS.
As you know, a generator uses a DPDT switch (such as 2 breakers with a sliding plate interlock between them) and your loads are "common".  In a DPDT switch, the two legs are never connected, and there isn't a failure mode you can imagine that would connect the two legs of a DPDT switch.  That makes things easy!
The UPS is the same deal.
For these cheaper portable power stations, they are 1-way beasts. Power comes in one port (Where the recharge cable connects) and goes out a different port (socket on its front). Power flow is one-way.  We still have to contend with the output conflicting with utility power, but that is easily handled by any of the above transfer switches used for generators.
Now we get to the fun part: grid-forming inverters like the PowerWall.   Those use "a sort of" DPDT transfer switch, but each leg is physically separated and one is software.   The utility leg is a special isolation switch called "MID". Microgrid isolation device.  It is an isolation switch, really just a powered disconnect that severs the utility connection.
When the grid-forming inverter is in utility mode, it acts like solar panels, obeying UL 1741 grid-following standards.  This means it is listening for stable frequency (grid not generator) and reactivity that "looks like the grid" (voltage and impedance doesn't rapidly increase when it pushes more power).  It is able to generate onto the grid, e.g. to sell your battery capacity to the utility during peak events, but it is behaving like a grid-tied solar panel, "Grid Following" and shutting down at loss of grid.
However. When the MID disconnects from the utility, the grid-forming inverter changes the way it inverts.  Now it goes into "Grid Forming" mode, where it generates power like a portable power station, but with a twist - it emulates the frequency and reactivity of the grid.   Guess what effect this has on UL 1741 solar panels!  Yes, they now think they are on the grid, and they power up. They are generating power, recharging the battery.  But to keep them generating power, the grid-forming inverter must precisely slurp up this solar production just like the grid would, preventing a voltage or impedance rise that would clue the solar panels into the fact that they're not on the grid.  When the inverter can no longer do this due to full battery, it adjusts the frequency slightly and the solar realizes it is not on grid and stops generating per UL 1741.
So the solar is "AC-coupled" to the battery - it feeds via AC power.
To say they are "slick" is an understatement.
Anyway, I have yet to see any home backup solutions built around these "portable power stations" that has the sophistication of a grid-forming inverter. Their ability to absorb solar is limited to a special MPPT inlet on the unit which is DC-coupled to small solar panels they sell or which meet the spec of the unit.  They can't use the house's installed solar.  But their advertising materials are very evasive on this point, they'd really like you to think that.  Misunderstanding or misleading on details like this are a hazard in consumer products this technically complex.

This is an excellent response, thank you! It clarifies some of the basis for my original question. It does raise a question: In the scenario where a portable power station's inverter output isn't aligned with the grid (frequency/THD?), why does that matter? The downstream/load devices won't care (right?), and from the numbers I've seen, portable power stations produce "cleaner" power than the grid. So why is grid-forming so important when the MID disconnects from the utility? I know grid synchronization is very complicated, especially after a major outage. Is it for when it reconnects?

@Monochrome the portable power station cannot back-feed the utility, period. Now if you throw the switch over from utility to backup source (any) and they're not in sync, electronic and resistive loads won't care but it can knock motors for a hell of a loop (and flow a LOT of current).  One guy had his furnace combustion blower start running backwards, filling the house with exhaust! So it's really better to have a good gap of time and not a "live" changeover.  For computers, put them on literal UPS's.

PPS creating cleaner power than the grid sounds like propaganda. Hard to make a real sine wave. But even if that were true, it takes more than a clean sine wave to fool a UL 1741 grid-tie inverter. When the UL 1741 inverter starts pushing energy into the grid, it has to behave like a grid.  AC mechanics is complicated and gives me a headache, honestly.  Here, watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uOSnQM1Zu4w

Most inverters do not like being backfed themselves. Which mean that connecting the output of the powerstation to the grid is more likely going to either damage the power station or trigger an internal safety.
In your diagram if the power station/ups has separate in and out and the critical loads subpanel has a proper transfer switch OR the critical loads subpanel is fed exclusively from the output of the power station with no direct connection to the main panel then it is safe.
The latter option is a typical UPS configuration used for servers in a datacenter. The grid feeds the UPS and the UPS feeds the servers. Internally the UPS might have a feed through for normal operation and have a quick failover mechanism that will isolate the output from the grid to the satisfaction of the UL.

Thank you! So I updated my diagram, since it didn't accurately reflect that the critical loads subpanel would have an integrated transfer switch (such as Reliance Controls 306CRK which is UL 1008 listed) to give the option of switching individual circuits from being fed from either the generator or the grid. In other words, only one or the other. If my new diagram is clearer, I think I am indeed describing what is done in a datacenter. What do you think?

In typical installs it's all or nothing, either all the circuits are fed from the backup, or they are all on the grid. But as long as you can guarantee the isolation between UPS output and the grid it should be possible.

For a computer / data center it is critical to have not only backup, but continuous power. What the answer describes (correctly) is an "online" type UPS where power always flows through the UPS system. That type of design provides other advantages, like the ability to raise a sagging line voltage and filtering some of the power gremlins that affect computers more than most things. That comes with the disadvantage that the UPS system carries the entire load 24x7.

@SteveI there are UPSs that will do a pass-through and do a failover internally. That results in less conversion loss during normal operation.

Yes - there are many ways to skin that particular cat, and I used the term 'online UPS' broadly to sidestep a discussion of the minutiae. At a system level, an online UPS design is where power goes into the UPS, which then supplies the equipment. It's arguable whether a specific unit qualifies as "online" when the the UPS decides for itself to bypass the double-conversion - and - does the switching internally.

That discussion is useful here because it changes the question to how things are connected, and whether a specific power station is designed / rated / spec'ed to perform as an "online" UPS with input and output always connected.

Thanks both of you for the discussion, I didn't realize that a datacenter's downstream equipment is fed only from the UPS. I assumed in a datacenter that there would be a way to use direct grid power in case the UPS fails. But I'd imagine the datacenter's UPS equipment is probably much nicer and provides cleaner power than the grid anyway.

Every proper backup power installation must include a transfer switch with a lockout device that will prevent backfeed via the breaker panel's connection to the grid. So this question is an important one.
The latest crop of solar power equipment also supports battery storage, and it is all designed to connect into the existing electrical system of your house. Which means they have to solve the same problem as Bluetti, etc. And the solution is just what you might expect... another product to sell. The National Electric Code refers to the solution generically as microgrid interconnect devices (or MID, if you're into TLAs).
EcoFlow has a Smart Home Panel to go with their home-sized batteries. Anker Solix has something similar called the Smart Home Power Kit. Those combine the switch to transfer from grid to backup power with circuit-level load switching (like the fancy one in the question). And there is an app, of course. If you prefer, Anker will bundle the same kind of transfer switch people have been using with backup generators for decades — which just goes to show that they all do the same job.
Bluetti has an entirely new system that is more like the Tesla PowerWall. There is also a lot of solar + battery equipment that goes together the same way. All of them have a box that is the MID, which connects the battery or solar power to your main panel and handles transfer and lockout. Tesla calls their box the System Controller, the solar equipment companies like Enphase, SolarEdge, Solis all have different names for theirs.
So the short answer is... as magical as they make these house-sized battery backups seem, there is no magic. Only technology.

What I am getting at here is that a proper installation -will- have a switch and interlock like a conventional generator, with some real examples of what is being sold today.
An important part of your question seems whether these things can be installed and used continuously, like a UPS. The manufacturers are promoting and selling (some of) their products for permanent, hard-wired installation. It would be difficult to sell electrical equipment without minimal compliance with certifications and such, so I hope that is not happening.

Thanks Steve, this gives me some more data! Yeah I hope they're meeting UL 1008 requirements at a minimum so they don't backfeed. I guess what makes the integrated "Smart Home Panel" solutions nice is that it handles the UPS switching requirements (fast switchover) and eliminates the clunkiness of a manual transfer switch/interlock in the loop. Effectively it seems like the same automatic transfer switch technology Generac has been selling for decades, without the delay to fire up a whole home gas generator. Is it correct terminology to say the "smart" panels effectively create an online UPS?
